# Приоритет классов

Tags: html, css

Проблема с которой я, что очень странно, еще не встречался. У меня есть структура подобная этой:

```
<div class="items-wrap">
    <a class="colink"></a>
</div>
```

И такие классы: `.items-wrap a`, `.colink`.

Проблема в том что к ссылке привязывается именно `.items-wrap a`, а локальный класс `.colink` полностью игнорируется.

Почему это так? И как мне это исправить?

Comment: смотря, что вы имеете ввиду. если вы задаёте одно и то же свойство обоим селекторам, то "вес" селектора `.items-wrap a` больше, чем `.colink`. потому его свойтсва важнее

Comment: покажите определения стилей этих css-классов

Comment: @lexxl Верно, они повторяються в большинстве. Единственный вариант что я сейчас вижу это использование !important, но мне кажеться это не совсем правильно. Проблема в том что это не моя работа и использование `.items-wrap a` придется удалять на десятках страниц. Нужно найти простое решение, которое переплюнет сей селектор.

Comment: @Levelleor `!Important` лучше избегать, иначе в какой-то момент у вас пол проекта в них будет. В крайних случаях его стоит применять... А вам лучше повысить вес селектора...чтоб тот был больше, чем `.items-wrap a` например сделать так `.items-wrap a.colink`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский гениально, благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените .colink на a.colink в сss-файле.

```
.items-wrap a { color: red; } a.colink { color: green; }
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/j2u6nhLn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Почитайте вот тут](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie) и увеличьте вес вашего селектора удобным/приемлевым вам способом. Наример, `.items-wrap a.colink` или `.items-wrap .colink`